# Entity mapping: Problems when referencing two properties to a foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the entities `Base`, `club` and `Transfer` below:

`Base`:

```
namespace ProjetoFutBr.Domain.Entities
{
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Club`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjetoFutBr.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Club : BaseEntity
    {
        public int IdClub { get; set; }
        public int Division { get; set; }
        public List<string> Competicoes { get; set; }
        public decimal Income { get; set; }
        public string Stadium { get; set; }

    }
}
```

`Transfer`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjetoFutBr.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Transfer
    {
        public int TransferId { get; set; }
        public string TypeTransfer { get; set; }
        public decimal? TransferValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransferDate { get; set; }

        public int OriginClub { get; set; }
        public int DestinationClub { get; set; }
        public virtual Club Club { get; set; }

        public int PlayerTraded { get; set; }
        public virtual Player Player { get; set; }


    }
}
```

I need to do a transfer mapping, so that both the `OriginClub` property and the `DestinationClub` property point to `ClubId`. I'm doing the following configuration in `TransferConfiguration`:

```
using ProjetoFutBr.Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjetoFutBr.Infra.Data.Mapping
{
    public class TransferConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Transfer>
    {
        public TransferConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(t => t.TransferId);

            Property(t => t.TypeTransfer)
                .IsRequired();

            HasRequired(t => t.Club)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.OriginClub);

            HasRequired(t => t.Club)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.DestinationClub);

            HasRequired(t => t.Player)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.PlayerTraded);

        }
    }
}
```

However, when I update the Database, only `DestinationClub` is marked as ForeignKey which points to `ClubId` and I need `ClubId` to be referenced as well. How can I also mark this property as foreignKey? Is there a more elegant way of portraying this business rule (A transfer has a destination club and a source club)?

I will put below the context class and the configuration of the clubs entity:

`ClubConfiguration`:

```
using ProjetoFutBr.Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjetoFutBr.Infra.Data.Mapping
{
    public class ClubConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Club>
    {
        public ClubConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(c => c.IdClub);

            Property(c => c.Name)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(c => c.Division)
                .IsRequired();

        }

    }
}
```

`ProjetoFutBr`:

```
using ProjetoFutBr.Domain.Entities;
using ProjetoFutBr.Infra.Data.Mapping;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjetoFutBr.Infra.Data.Context
{
    public class ProjetoFutBrContexto : DbContext
    {
        public ProjetoFutBrContexto()
            : base("ProjetoFutBr")
        {

        }


        public DbSet<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transfer> Transfers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Properties()
                .Where(p => p.Name == p.ReflectedType.Name + "Id")
                .Configure(p => p.IsKey());

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClubConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PlayerConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TransferConfiguration());

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot have two FKs to the same navigation property.  You should have one for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have two navigation properties for each of the FKs  Also I suggest using the "Id" suffix for the actual FK values and the proper names for the navigation properties.

```
public class Transfer
{
    ...
    public int OriginClubId { get; set; }
    public int DestinationClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual Club OriginClub { get; set; }
    public virtual Club DestinationClub { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then you can do the mapping like this

```
HasRequired(t => t.OriginClub)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.OriginClubId);

HasRequired(t => t.DestinationClub)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.DestinationClubId);
```

Additionally you might want to consider creating the navigation properties on `Club` back to `Transfer`.

```
public Club
{
    ...
    ICollection<Transfer> OriginTransfers { get; set; }
    ICollection<Transfer> DestinationTransfers { get; set; }
}
```

Then the mapping would be

```
HasRequired(t => t.OriginClub)
    .WithMany(c => c.OriginTransfers)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.OriginClubId);

HasRequired(t => t.DestinationClub)
    .WithMany(c => c.DestinationTransfers)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.DestinationClubId);
```